# Plot data.frame in R with ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a list of data frames like :

```
      out = list(structure(list(DLC41ms = c(0.0031633859810912, 0.121520954862548, 
0.123617669347512, 0.129348870659286, 0.185113267199568, 0.260688273927753, 
0.293583723552447, 0.297108478910199, 0.284979540913941, 0.285360416955637, 
0.277273203197587, 0.265924489053568, 0.243859111154412, 0.229095516920215, 
0.193723860107464, 0.169379206447382, 0.135389835451235, 0.107304402977301, 
0.0753978064138843, 0.0389266842035347, 0.013348618834338, 0.00335417641912744
), `hYUN_p07-i01_ClusterC2_ILA1` = c(-52.5, -43.375, -34.25, 
-25.125, -16, -6.375, 3.25, 12.875, 22.5, 22.5, 29.467, 36.433, 
43.4, 51.1, 58.8, 66.5, 74.2, 81.4, 88.6, 95.8, 103, 110.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L)), structure(list(DLC64h = c(0.00343783271186764, 1.06349409996102, 
1.04667922660965, 1.05739737426366, 1.2009737414251, 1.34198171391244, 
1.41037653788597, 1.39843919377863, 1.31487869047025, 1.31707204759337, 
1.24794982386622, 1.16244825009117, 1.05998107861483, 0.945539545735093, 
0.810207490164157, 0.670470450823383, 0.52527828693085, 0.393307678470125, 
0.253483138003207, 0.125592625134136, 0.0383912764363229, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), DLC64h = c(0.0182870979585783, 0.0839347127169774, 0.0820496752995642, 
0.0796857104239288, 0.076636326694896, 0.0740981166600861, 0.0721110662241128, 
0.0702821912443217, 0.068262891201914, 0.0641913719951261, 0.0596382546252066, 
0.055788498958326, 0.0524256485857287, 0.0506570165684668, 0.0488086020039789, 
0.0479032070902036, 0.0472705352464485, 0.0472208188406132, 0.0469824183154683, 
0.047018264107552, 0.0470103357329518, 0.0470375440907054, 0.0470562310613325, 
0.0470744546889209, 0.0470743166442109, 0.0470768477898976, 0.0470842802403169, 
0.0469135562298176, 0.0468468543689422, 0.0467067657278952, 0.0463100258520136, 
0.0455636924415753, 0.0445267949801028, 0.0426557188239823, 0.038274989651877, 
0.0283840679055483, 0.010545582038612, 0.000509047901546849), 
    DLC64h = c(0.0682039035949202, 0.383871502474758, 0.388491367390502, 
    0.395755233673989, 0.393883110591027, 0.38357754392518, 0.371192627641175, 
    0.35879623584899, 0.352773981770983, 0.354202342501633, 0.356355111673662, 
    0.356394798433093, 0.358206787817173, 0.358829611133505, 
    0.356503939797175, 0.352564074882189, 0.344411784577679, 
    0.33324366230195, 0.315954338887504, 0.291798989347465, 0.248258599757461, 
    0.167373696825949, 0.0562840185760291, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `hYUN_p07-i01_ClusterC2_ILA1` = c(-52.5, 
    -43.375, -34.25, -25.125, -16, -6.375, 3.25, 12.875, 22.5, 
    22.5, 29.467, 36.433, 43.4, 51.1, 58.8, 66.5, 74.2, 81.4, 
    88.6, 95.8, 103, 110.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, 
    -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, 
    -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 
    15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 
    66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, 
    -66, -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 
    12.5, 12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 
    70.84, 78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)), structure(list(DLC64l = c(2.45692655312564e-16, 1.90268291100716, 
1.90734606271009, 2.00968790284476, 3.15314431238807, 4.79594454391171, 
5.29316146375101, 5.24590709808705, 4.85531024823933, 4.86232591566839, 
4.5896820926463, 4.22177579070747, 3.85622595630147, 3.43124349080794, 
2.92657229461866, 2.38158734440488, 1.82091534585416, 1.32811381255006, 
0.834033610589599, 0.368749633593734, 0.0810811404823062, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), DLC64l = c(0.0775171406532654, 0.136702540728187, 0.142469508908647, 
0.149231381067624, 0.161133814696488, 0.167862427276489, 0.17885757493889, 
0.188322549460057, 0.202204943826697, 0.224182401507779, 0.254595240391027, 
0.286367621990186, 0.321106527467607, 0.343385548016078, 0.368605928920641, 
0.385543414984002, 0.396247373648929, 0.40012566445517, 0.401342670672085, 
0.402437063371678, 0.402637227970377, 0.403164610194465, 0.403551159543014, 
0.403880956940561, 0.403983023240631, 0.403923084291875, 0.404867616058887, 
0.403980604314669, 0.402569298127318, 0.400532852311185, 0.397459089076149, 
0.391746603729568, 0.381778845419467, 0.363069910185862, 0.322814659309606, 
0.234950590644019, 0.0814069596737419, 0.00231177596624174), 
    DLC64l = c(0.0491324764617038, 0.000646464542124482, 0.000667879850640206, 
    0.000701790359459709, 0.000841724333258625, 0.00114200742199224, 
    0.00131740059947369, 0.00136310896030365, 0.00144901162200778, 
    0.00145565011406664, 0.00145811522861758, 0.00145829151877925, 
    0.00147135248013787, 0.00147067631008413, 0.00146381996555089, 
    0.00144440003600201, 0.00141179438808945, 0.00136721892293532, 
    0.00130176688585897, 0.00120290010563353, 0.00102531633992181, 
    0.000721485552802989, 0.000232649267060849, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `hYUN_p07-i01_ClusterC2_ILA1` = c(-52.5, 
    -43.375, -34.25, -25.125, -16, -6.375, 3.25, 12.875, 22.5, 
    22.5, 29.467, 36.433, 43.4, 51.1, 58.8, 66.5, 74.2, 81.4, 
    88.6, 95.8, 103, 110.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, 
    -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, 
    -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 
    15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 
    66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, 
    -66, -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 
    12.5, 12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 
    70.84, 78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)), structure(list(DLC72 = c(0.010632549076346, 10.6665113713504, 
10.6504031115509, 10.9831880316785, 15.1507951176905, 19.7728875452393, 
21.3160399803826, 21.129890796314, 19.7584904417584, 19.8005074388411, 
18.7410956878111, 17.3610969737621, 15.7731898324797, 13.9335136600018, 
11.8308219233181, 9.64642262338299, 7.41862411058014, 5.38949255816869, 
3.34519959854764, 1.50041053717485, 0.347198822980415, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    DLC72 = c(12.8285125272045, 27.7174734513101, 28.3316401334511, 
    29.256542779264, 30.6246707905386, 31.6699168051135, 32.8819635133752, 
    34.1649407374231, 35.6110979096556, 38.2796146505173, 41.8962654706474, 
    45.1383666690901, 48.3080092139444, 50.3076743911529, 52.8858478548286, 
    54.5184923343358, 55.2966832740955, 55.5491526463063, 55.5957899295336, 
    55.667166920044, 55.6818893443367, 55.7634023590981, 55.8064843463865, 
    55.8915800656335, 55.893319160544, 55.8862534124851, 55.9165806339803, 
    55.8240611726336, 55.5521705397113, 55.1749962743074, 54.5682675961309, 
    53.6116011854643, 52.161334621191, 49.3882335062894, 43.724881210651, 
    31.4614232630774, 10.535821537889, 0.253705252865466), DLC72 = c(8.336495144341, 
    36.1745297466092, 38.0024519770216, 41.4219739594744, 46.169603890161, 
    50.8277951216586, 54.8483955416169, 57.3059654863845, 57.6667222086439, 
    57.9424246003873, 58.1910628562599, 58.1986690819518, 58.4265648533366, 
    58.4351633910753, 58.0802412959206, 57.3306586991926, 56.0356771397037, 
    54.0588453495766, 51.1170782368227, 46.8800604490026, 39.3644742856029, 
    25.8834017175556, 7.9801308355807, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `hYUN_p07-i01_ClusterC2_ILA1` = c(-52.5, 
    -43.375, -34.25, -25.125, -16, -6.375, 3.25, 12.875, 22.5, 
    22.5, 29.467, 36.433, 43.4, 51.1, 58.8, 66.5, 74.2, 81.4, 
    88.6, 95.8, 103, 110.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, 
    -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, 
    -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 
    15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 
    66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, 
    -66, -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 
    12.5, 12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 
    70.84, 78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)), structure(list(DLC12 = c(86.5314866162036, 70.6482044279903, 
70.0517266430886, 69.1537430043123, 67.8241590098885, 66.7921442938182, 
65.5937980140176, 64.3261418720238, 62.8913534820884, 60.2489665221705, 
56.6753714303144, 53.4520540590501, 50.3068923447928, 48.3126391408391, 
45.7382293718082, 44.108630511863, 43.321486762861, 43.0602315026524, 
43.0111480492834, 42.9379605954284, 42.9223167319234, 42.8396978977298, 
42.7920754385132, 42.7049422833556, 42.7031174954913, 42.7102891219321, 
42.6748905084158, 42.7650978277989, 43.0372974233205, 43.4160213230891, 
44.0275002603808, 44.9961254558944, 46.4686932865709, 49.2809912275468, 
55.0431218863332, 67.5331329321333, 88.8867737872429, 99.4150369800821
), DLC12 = c(54.4435251593895, 60.4058230578194, 58.6303989612682, 
55.314337253841, 50.7710434064941, 46.4037703430297, 42.6359255249323, 
40.3038329424453, 39.8819638103591, 39.5582413841129, 39.2469336458061, 
39.2393700712619, 38.9400585523699, 38.8578597755466, 39.1476476831477, 
39.8302872496507, 41.0591799377689, 42.9639100534251, 45.8265164643939, 
50.0114270438487, 57.5147424189172, 71.1293758377103, 89.5087392552777, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, 
    -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, 
    -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 
    35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 
    95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, -66, 
    -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 12.5, 
    12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 70.84, 
    78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)), structure(list(DLC24a = c(0.218766367916309, 0.153340002337096, 
0.151650969728312, 0.149187928295569, 0.145890364320125, 0.143446126578526, 
0.140964905342863, 0.13812392978371, 0.135383865353581, 0.129413735907879, 
0.121387699080614, 0.113569036243044, 0.105845095969524, 0.100510612892751, 
0.0936069324743029, 0.0894943486944327, 0.0876085925358724, 0.0870050065625371, 
0.0869819496723875, 0.0868380015765139, 0.0868212695787194, 0.0866958376348893, 
0.086645708728405, 0.0865151999281387, 0.0865135517201478, 0.086534186426046, 
0.0865103663171702, 0.0869378045250614, 0.0879836961420589, 0.0894183411748553, 
0.0913138598157845, 0.0945822436516908, 0.0995456234554365, 0.109125877997524, 
0.127380884153403, 0.165166562786197, 0.224581307428501, 0.251060887424037
), DLC24a = c(0.159886150336981, 0.171677716391787, 0.166377841964712, 
0.156878943554993, 0.144906495222232, 0.132883089000661, 0.122449254454408, 
0.116110146641472, 0.115259375778084, 0.114175047208234, 0.113332296094903, 
0.113304603571124, 0.112510701057897, 0.112551069962873, 0.113587724778825, 
0.115526596882998, 0.11894812242382, 0.124318407579698, 0.13248316606602, 
0.143755537700758, 0.16258338643667, 0.195528593960096, 0.235012447394, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, 
    -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, 
    -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 
    35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 
    95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, -66, 
    -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 12.5, 
    12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 70.84, 
    78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)), structure(list(DLC24b = c(0.0453214145449118, 0.0485214988383027, 
0.0474234852066369, 0.0459975660528709, 0.0439642773383507, 0.0424344466295988, 
0.0406291833428262, 0.0385910882375923, 0.0362724179811376, 0.0321579400348675, 
0.0268641424420976, 0.0224727618666185, 0.0186253035799354, 0.016430726972427, 
0.0137797008874603, 0.0122595872705079, 0.0116178253111307, 0.0114085223571877, 
0.0113579355162143, 0.0113600872937264, 0.0113676459438673, 0.0113948338535472, 
0.011409838002603, 0.0114454746305702, 0.011450626850776, 0.011457147558928, 
0.0115163765216727, 0.0116571243037127, 0.0118928895947969, 0.0122033597385413, 
0.012615206546191, 0.0132434489398068, 0.0142137755219769, 0.016076497250941, 
0.019648872676804, 0.0273543945082651, 0.0403086813652211, 0.0469900438394219
), DLC24b = c(0.0184136799547997, 0.0292407180672802, 0.0281028927262214, 
0.0255667376929854, 0.0215804758294541, 0.017381680478672, 0.0140059337827739, 
0.0118466008198282, 0.011287638730048, 0.0112765092353713, 0.0112329422618099, 
0.0112330297626183, 0.011237752427963, 0.0112795563693597, 0.0113607823334111, 
0.0115973921926224, 0.0119648096088683, 0.012380757457651, 0.0131655540718474, 
0.0141270419507646, 0.015891534764751, 0.0188195794912396, 0.021878775274657, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, 
    -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, 
    -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 
    35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 
    95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, -66, 
    -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 12.5, 
    12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 70.84, 
    78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)), structure(list(DLC31 = c(0.114275756371283, 0.419696415865509, 
0.418166663471472, 0.41659770277584, 0.412075330325881, 0.406296316875646, 
0.404865668230333, 0.40199122147391, 0.397664754098204, 0.384758065118196, 
0.359611489738715, 0.337066381557038, 0.31049067851873, 0.296809210627832, 
0.277196869667497, 0.25971047000425, 0.249450511536022, 0.249950166945168, 
0.249844869268875, 0.250428445647417, 0.251203765820931, 0.251349743180014, 
0.252974109262994, 0.254301841336695, 0.2542961137628, 0.254257827350519, 
0.254994504577032, 0.25585846552889, 0.257852426051227, 0.256590902847481, 
0.255201118353802, 0.253687786597228, 0.249522336846397, 0.243218992806048, 
0.221457233295584, 0.173167673208189, 0.0745166521363018, 0.0118927335597613
), DLC31 = c(0.105191462635085, 0.376068325580247, 0.376822148945267, 
0.368943653977019, 0.33636158761232, 0.284947878504001, 0.2400420288855, 
0.20608995012619, 0.203680811762795, 0.204922698290645, 0.206917758925312, 
0.206942866445647, 0.208514117710556, 0.213361180672979, 0.212624193011083, 
0.210194540549773, 0.207716791456246, 0.202430582734739, 0.19696461613771, 
0.18522171342043, 0.162299056496549, 0.118762287053893, 0.0497061292818597, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, 
    -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, 
    -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 
    35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 
    95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, -66, 
    -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 12.5, 
    12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 70.84, 
    78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)), structure(list(DLC41e = c(0.00112022892793795, 0.00529857259283213, 
0.00513886656639065, 0.00513577550831923, 0.00498318974912717, 
0.00480864175452075, 0.00470534905551177, 0.00454405919690493, 
0.00433509316194446, 0.00405282002645228, 0.00364043874229719, 
0.0034119775767327, 0.00328861599936114, 0.00312180175858676, 
0.00310300107191918, 0.00313168682770946, 0.00308698623499945, 
0.00313006479484543, 0.0031106433039962, 0.0031909369600748, 
0.00319303983239588, 0.00319862778736807, 0.00325414565866252, 
0.00329720389330231, 0.00329712683247052, 0.00329662311976585, 
0.00338449846497849, 0.00342986707917998, 0.00344435269388162, 
0.00355370257450106, 0.00356588396586719, 0.00357608951969794, 
0.00364849556003587, 0.00365630346193987, 0.00353623622574113, 
0.00306495528827925, 0.00187087677534341, 0.000767246364903308
), DLC41e = c(0.00199259615219407, 0.00993957948672134, 0.0101554562378574, 
0.0101560159924302, 0.0106651651113587, 0.0104559651129055, 0.0106576811811128, 
0.0108636812239941, 0.0110594342077646, 0.0110975125031564, 0.01114685873109, 
0.0111482116879716, 0.0114046785560539, 0.0115137687759619, 0.0115393723104415, 
0.0114074345887843, 0.0113445432723503, 0.0111061333243449, 0.0106024728241209, 
0.009886717682106, 0.00858079186869025, 0.00619948404416043, 
0.0024922245932218, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, -65, -60, -55, 
-50, -47.5, -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, 
-7, -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 
35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 
95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, -66, -56.6, 
-47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 12.5, 12.5, 19.467, 
26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 70.84, 78.04, 85.24, 
92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 38L)), structure(list(
    DLC41i = c(0.138464782241703, 0.695771145407792, 0.678656847723093, 
    0.652820987658641, 0.614220855768878, 0.605164592690514, 
    0.589061464097191, 0.572828114303108, 0.558357480317725, 
    0.535805938686013, 0.503462966788739, 0.487773144497363, 
    0.467908482509039, 0.460694215981115, 0.45963949544064, 0.461477965786566, 
    0.469472540586466, 0.474132286796177, 0.475879264138292, 
    0.476130032032328, 0.476039141738809, 0.475900902572461, 
    0.476477622436718, 0.476544187858097, 0.476533064150817, 
    0.476514638318387, 0.478818676742515, 0.478351963263727, 
    0.476193805833404, 0.476028888774189, 0.472995262719091, 
    0.466040255253569, 0.455126942007137, 0.434475457645546, 
    0.390287233376125, 0.288899027555097, 0.106243915751312, 
    0.0059031597088719), DLC41i = c(0.0763052952592319, 0.480698795794534, 
    0.484636373649032, 0.488443139980859, 0.484223512236868, 
    0.45008230602985, 0.416449313587552, 0.389629202260568, 0.375495512850925, 
    0.377397517190444, 0.381124504812132, 0.381170763638473, 
    0.383605301298594, 0.385283553119306, 0.383183928045964, 
    0.380587068011987, 0.372613918151571, 0.360618300981876, 
    0.342602503938473, 0.317236790747977, 0.27105301415066, 0.182777789727521, 
    0.0617505616005118, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, -65, 
    -60, -55, -50, -47.5, -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, -25, 
    -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 15, 
    21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 
    66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, 
    -66, -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 
    12.5, 12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 
    70.84, 78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)), structure(list(DLC41m = c(0.02624806797749, 0.0910572322126005, 
0.0910772065561211, 0.0910571646406683, 0.0922660406795948, 0.0938282326027338, 
0.0930432613754086, 0.0942342368535042, 0.0950671623148232, 0.0968565540355199, 
0.0991628672292148, 0.103129849170706, 0.10540808863291, 0.108077335190526, 
0.111182242896488, 0.113356473143196, 0.117075597943824, 0.11764332028936, 
0.117562270295499, 0.117469653538374, 0.117521497121909, 0.118157643858692, 
0.120071400406781, 0.120418331734363, 0.120415520762977, 0.120397110727542, 
0.121352538681384, 0.123711614322062, 0.123748714156593, 0.123947589454718, 
0.124771697159254, 0.123833238508253, 0.121609278447632, 0.118496507991892, 
0.108596794326569, 0.0844565328933596, 0.037930699698903, 0.0118228722878775
), DLC41m = c(0.108423763069501, 0.213642296571627, 0.224021470123322, 
0.235703458986629, 0.247437705979371, 0.255629062531108, 0.260051914144357, 
0.263430377810683, 0.264315432068389, 0.265150461368426, 0.265787300849609, 
0.265818825867519, 0.269749171357754, 0.270860446221749, 0.269684829550434, 
0.267126140943506, 0.263919871046971, 0.256284443998711, 0.245964175707705, 
0.22687385585044, 0.19454871946828, 0.133912779773782, 0.049586430015697, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `hSAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = c(-69.3, -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, 
    -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, 
    -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 
    35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 
    95.54, 102.74), `hNnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = c(-75.4, -66, 
    -56.6, -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 12.5, 
    12.5, 19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 70.84, 
    78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
38L)))
```

I would like to plot each data frame in separate plot (in this case 11 plot).
some of data frames like `out[[1]]` are straightforward. there is 2 column `h` in y axis and the other column in x-axis.

`ggplot(out[[1]],aes(DLC41ms,`hYUN_p07-i01_ClusterC2_ILA1`)) + geom_point()`

how I could do that for the `out[[3]]` since there I have 6 column the first and forth column are a pair to plot, then the second and fifth column and then the third and six column :
[image]
and at the end all should be in a loop or kind of apply function for all the data frames in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to pivot to long format and then plot each of them with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
ggs <- map(out, ~ {i1 <- !startsWith(names(.x), 'h')
           names(.x)[i1] <- str_c(names(.x)[i1], seq_len(sum(i1)), sep='_')
           names(.x)[!i1] <- str_replace(names(.x)[!i1], "(\\d+)$", "_\\1")
           pivot_longer(.x, cols = everything(), names_to = c('.value', 'group'),
                names_sep = "_", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
              ggplot(aes(x = !! rlang::sym(names(.)[2]), y = h, col = group)) +
                 geom_line()})
```

#### Update

With the updated dataset, we can change the delimiter

```
ggs <- map(out, ~ {
         i1 <- !startsWith(names(.x), 'h')            

         names(.x)[i1] <- str_c(names(.x)[i1], 
             str_remove(names(.x)[!i1], "^h"), sep=':')
        names(.x)[!i1] <- str_replace(names(.x)[!i1], "^(h)", "h:")


      pivot_longer(.x, cols = everything(), names_to = c('.value', 'group'), 
          names_sep = ":", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
                 ggplot(aes(x = !! rlang::sym(names(.)[2]), y = h, col = group)) + 
                           geom_point() +
                            geom_path()
                   })
```

-checking

```
ggs[[3]]
```

[image]

Comment: @user9112767 the 'ggs' object can be saved into a pdf or loop over list and save it to different jpeg

Comment: what if I want to see them like when using `facet_wrap()` in ggplot ? all plots next to each other ?

Comment: @user9112767  you meant all `ggs` ?

Comment: @user9112767 with lots of plots, it may not be easier to have this in a single plot.  But you can check `ggarrange` from `ggpubr` or patchwork from [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork)

Comment: @ akrun yes, each ggs, is one plot. Put all in a kind of layout next to each other